# Python's List: form a new list B of member attributes of object list A

Tags: python, list

Could expert in Python help out:

listA is a list of objects. each Object has a member attribute called 'name'

What is easiest way to create a new list, ListB,  that contains all names of ListA.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not give us a list of way you think to create a new list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listB = [obj.name for obj in listA]
```

Comment: OMG you are brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.name=b`
```

and a list like

```
listA=[]
listA.append(A("x"))
listA.append(A("y"))
listA.append(A("z"))
```

you can do something like this:

```
listB=[x.name for x in listA]
```

Comment: Nice answer, but `listA = [A("x"), A("y"), A("z")]` is less verbose than doing all those `append`s